# Can I use mysql's md5 function in an update?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I don't know how to ask this so I'll start with what I have already:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `questions` SET `votes` = `votes` + 1 
WHERE `questionID`='".md5($_GET['q'])."'");
```

What I want to do is update the row where the md5 hashed version of `questionID` = some string. Can I do this using MySQL's md5 function?

#### Edit:

Would it be something like this then:

```
"WHERE MD5(`questionID`)='".md5($_GET['q'])."'"
```

Comment: no way to do that You compare two identical strings. Perhaps you mean "WHERE questionID=MD5(". $_GET['q'] .")". <- This assume that the value in your Database is a MD5 hash. Then you ask MySQL to convert $_GET['q'] to a MD5 Hash and compare it with the value in the database.

Comment: questionID is not hashed in the database.  Its a index number.  I didnt want people to see ?q=5412  so am doing ?q=a9e5cc03183b0dc0a4929393e9d77796 and then trying to update the row whre md5('5412') = 'a9e5cc03183b0dc0a4929393e9d77796'

Comment: Ok, so your code is good, I didn't get it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, but in that code you're using PHP's [md5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php).

EDIT: If you want to search for a row where the hash of the questionID column equals the hash of `$_GET['q']`, the second looks right.  It's not clear what you're using MD5 for, though.  Maybe you should give some background.

EDIT 2: Since q is already hashed, it should be (with escaping):

```
"WHERE MD5(`questionID`)='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']) . "'"
```

Comment: You are true, but can you give him the correct syntax to help him ?

Comment: @J- 16, thanks, my snippet wasn't complete.  It assumed `$_GET['q']` had already been escaped.  However, I've shown it above instead.  An alternative (beyond the question) would be to use `PDO` or `mysqli` prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

Of course. MySQL's MD5 behavior is identical to PHP's MD5.

```
'WHERE MD5(field)="'.md5($field).'"'
```

Your method of passing `"q"` via `$_GET` isn't secure though. Makes no sense hashing it when the fact that `?q=` is visible to users on the browser's address bar. You may want to preprocess `"q"` thru a Javascript MD5 function first before form submission:

http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/

Comment: Yes, they know the hashed value.  But they couldn't, e.g. know that the next question ID was 5413.  So there are reasons to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use an MD5 hash in this way I would suggest precomputing the hashed value of questionID and storing it in a column of the questions table.  Index this column.  If you used an indexed column in your WHERE clause MySQL merely looks at the index to find the matching rows.

If the column is not indexed, or you use a function such as MD5(), MySQL has to look at every single row in that database table to return the information you are looking for.  You will see a major performance boost with the indexed column, especially on larger datasets.

You may also wish to use a salt so that your MD5 hashes are not easily converted to their original value. See this URL for more information:

http://skfox.com/2007/12/18/md5-hashes-and-salt/

Comment: I don't have the rep to comment on stillstanding's answer so this is my only method of clarification.  MySQL MD5() will not give you the same hash if character set is different.
ex :
<?php
#suppose table_name CHARSET=UTF8
#$md5 = md5('Städte'); # will give you a different hash than MySQL MD5()
#instead use
$md5 = md5(utf8_encode('Städte'));
?>